# Start software after gnome-keyring is unlocked (using systemd or other means)

Tags: systemd, gnome-keyring

I have a piece of software that requires gnome-keyring to be unlocked to work. I want it to be started only after I have unlocked gnome-keyring by entering the password. Is this possible with systemd? Or in any other way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You will need [`systemd-ask-password`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-ask-password.html)
It is designed specifically for cases when you have a password-locked task and no user to type the password. Like have an encrypted HDD and you need to boot from it.

You will need to use `--keyname` option, and the `systemd-ask-password` will start appropriate `keyring` service, ask for the password, then continue with the task.